# Several "from" addresses

Tags: 8, emails

I would like to be able to send multiple emails that my site sends from different accounts. Is this possible in Drupal? I use Drupal 8 and SwiftMailer.

Comment: Yes.  How to change the account on the email depends on which emails you are talking about though.

Comment: It depends on your use case, if you don't want to write custom module, you can use Business Rules module (https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) that will allow you to do that (Make sure to include the needed module patches as the module still need some to work) and it integrates with the mail system, and though with Swift mailer. Maybe you need to consider switching Symfony Mailer instead of Swift mailer as it is absolute now